# $\mathcal{P}({\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{N}^{*}})=\sigma(S)$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbf{N}=\left\{1,2,...\right\},\mathbf{N}^{*}=\left\{1,2,...\right\}\cup\left\{{\infty}\right\}$.

Set $n$ be a positive integer,
$S:=\left\{ \prod_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}:S_{k}\subseteq \mathbf{N}\right\}$.

For an arbitrary set $X$, let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the collection of all subsets of $X$, $\sigma(X)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

Considering $\sigma(S)$ under the  measurable space $\left(\underbrace{\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{N}^{*}}_{n \text{ times the product of }  \mathbf{N}^{*}} ,\mathcal{P}(\underbrace{\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{N}^{*}}_{n \text{ times the product of }  \mathbf{N}^{*}})\right),$ do we have $\sigma(S)=\mathcal{P}(\underbrace{\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{N}^{*}}_{n \text{ times the product of }  \mathbf{N}^{*}})$?

$\sigma(S)\subseteq \mathcal{P}({\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{N}^{*}})$ is trivial.How to get the converse,$\mathcal{P}({\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{N}^{*}})\subseteq\sigma(S)$?

Comment: I fail to see how $\infty$ should come into this. $S$ contains tuples of subsest of $N$. If by union you mean component wise union, you still "only" get tuples of subsest of $N$.

Comment: @Ingix We should consider $\sigma(S)$ under the whole set $\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\mathbf{N}^{*}.$ If $A\in S$, the complement of $A$ under $\mathbf{N}^{*}\times\cdots\mathbf{N}^{*}$, can't be the subset of  $\mathbf{N}\times\cdots\mathbf{N}.$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no for $n>1$ and yes for $n=1$.

If we define for $X=(E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_n) \in S, \bar{X}= (N^*\backslash E_1, \ldots, N^*\backslash E_n)$, that is the component wise complement in $N^*\times\ldots N^*$, and for $Y \in \mathcal{P}(S)\; \bar{Y}$ as the element wise application of that, I claim that
$$ \sigma(S) = S \cup \bar{S}.$$

Obviously, $\bar{S} \subseteq \sigma(S)$, because the complement of every element of $S$ must be in it (one of the requirements of a $\sigma$-algebra). So we have $ \sigma(S) \supseteq S \cup \bar{S}$.

We prove the other direction of the inequality by showing that applying all the required (for a $\sigma$-algebra) operations on $S \cup \bar{S}$ will not create elements outside it.

The complement of a complement is the original element, so applying the complement operation on any element of $\bar{S}$ does not yield a new element.

Any countable union and intersection of elements of $S$ yield an element of $S$. By the above complement of a complement relation, that same can be proved for $\bar{S}$ (intersection in $S$ corresponds to union in $\bar{S}$ and vice versa).

So what remains to be checked to proof that $ \sigma(S) = S \cup \bar{S}$ is what happens when you join and intersect elements, some of which are subsets of $S$ and some of which are subsets of $\bar{S}$.

Since union and intersection are commutative and associative, we can first join/intersect the subsets of $S$ and $\bar{S}$ seperately, so we finally need to prove only that, for $A \in S$ and $B \in \bar{S}$ we have

$$ A \cup B \in S \cup \bar{S}, \; A \cap B \in S \cup \bar{S}$$

$A = (A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n) \in S$ means that none of $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ contain $\infty$ (definition of $S$ and $N$). OTOH, $B = (B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n) \in \bar{S}$ means that **each of** $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ contains $\infty$ (because it is a complement of an element of $S$, where no component has it).

In other words

$$\forall i=1,2,\ldots,n: \infty \in A_i \cup B_i ,\; \infty \notin A_i \cap B_i $$.

But that means exactly that $A \cup B \in \bar{S},\; A \cap B \in S$, hence the operations of union and intersection of elements of $S \cup \bar{S}$ are closed in that set.

That concludes our proof that indeed $ \sigma(S) = S \cup \bar{S}.$

For $n>1$, that mean something like $(\{\infty\},\emptyset,\emptyset, \ldots,\emptyset) \in \mathcal{P}(N^*\times \ldots \times N^*)$, but that same element is not in $\sigma (S)$.

For $n=1$, $S \cup \bar{S} = \mathcal{P}(N^*)$, because if $X \subseteq N^*$ does not contain $\infty$, we have $X \in S$ and if does contain $\infty$, we have $X \in \bar{S}$.